# pywhois on domains with multiple records

Tags: python, whois, pywhois

I'm trying to create a simple app that will allow me to run a whois, but I've hit a road block.

```
>>> w = pywhois.whois('google.com')
>>> print w
creation_date: []
domain_name: []
emails: []
...
```

I'm about 99% sure that I'm not getting any results because running:

```
$ whois google
```

fails due to multiple records but running "=xxx" will run a single record.

I can run a search this way using python-whois:

```
>>> w = whois.query('=google.com')
```

My solution would be sticking with python-whois but pywhois returns much more information.

Has anyone run into this before or have a work around for running a single record in pywhois?

Comment: Interesting that this snippet doesn't work since it is the lone example given on the pywhois project website. [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/)

Comment: @IamChuckB that is why I was very confused.
I came up with a hack work-around for the time being, by getting the IP and running it through a reverse lookup and doing a whois on that.  Seems to be working for far.